# Window not getting focus when clicking on a checkbox control inside it

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, macos-carbon

I have a problem in getting focus to a window in my Objective C Carbon application. When I click outside the window, then the window is out of focus. Then, when I click on a checkbox inside the window, the checkbox get selected, but the main window remains out of focus. 
I have tried using ActivateWindow() and other functions but none of them are working. What should I use to bring my window to the front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work using **SetFrontProcess(processSerialNumber)**

Comment: If the window all windows of that process were minimized, this would not un-minimize them would it? So it would do nothing? Did you have a work around to un-minimize? I'm having that issue right now.